# Error when using XML::Simple in Windows

Tags: xml, perl, module

Please find the error which I have got after installing `XML::Simple`. I have installed parser, xam, still I'm receiving the same error.

Error:

```
XMLin() requires either XML::SAX or XML::Parser at XML_parser1.pl line 12
```

Comment: Which Perl distribution are you using? There are 5 in common use for Windows. How did you install XML::Simple? [Its metafile](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/META.json) declares XML::SAX as dependency, how did you manage to break that?

Comment: Version is 5.12 , i just copied the pm file into lib directory.I'm trying on windows

Comment: That will not work. Are you using Strawberry Perl or Active Perl, or something else?

Comment: i m usigng Active Perl on windows

Answer (score 2):

Remove what you changed so far, and install the package the recommended way:

- [How to install CPAN modules into ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl)
- [XML-Simple PPM info](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-Simple/)

Answer (score 0):

Start by undoing the mangling of Perl's directories (deleting the files you copied into them), then install XML::Simple properly. The following will do with ActivePerl:

```
ppm install XML::Simple
```

No idea what "xam" is, but it's not one of the parsers requested.